# Gnulib config.h missing error

Tags: makefile, mingw, autotools, mingw-w64, gnulib

I'm trying to port [libisofs](https://dev.lovelyhq.com/libburnia/web/wikis/Libisofs) to Windows. My environment is MSYS2 with mingw-w64-i686 toolchain installed.

I've used gnulib for missing headers with
`gnulib-tool --import` command:

```
$ ../gnulib/gnulib-tool --import fnmatch
```

I've done all steps in instruction:

```
Don't forget to
  - add "lib/Makefile" to AC_CONFIG_FILES in ./configure.ac,
  - mention "lib" in SUBDIRS in Makefile.am,
  - mention "-I m4" in ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am,
  - mention "m4/gnulib-cache.m4" in EXTRA_DIST in Makefile.am,
  - invoke gl_EARLY in ./configure.ac, right after AC_PROG_CC,
  - invoke gl_INIT in ./configure.ac.
```

Altough, there was no `AC_PROG_CC` in configure.ac, so I've added `gl_EARLY` after `AM_PROG_CC_C_O`
And there was no `SUBDIRS` variable in `Makefile.am` so I've added it manually at the bottom, as so:

```
SUBDIRS = lib
```

All configurations I've made as so:

```
autoreconf -i
automake --add-missing
autoconf
./configure
```

After running make I recieve error:

```
hard-locale.c:19:10: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <config.h>
```

As I understand that file must be created by `./configure`, but I don't understand why compiler doesn't find it.

configure.ac: https://pastebin.com/JbWRqjEv 
Makefile.am: https://pastebin.com/V6ZBq8Vd 
All outputs: https://pastebin.com/WFu5aJU7

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] *in the question itself*.  Links to external documents do not suffice.  I suspect that a minimal top-level `configure.ac` will be sufficient, actually, but it's not really complete without a corresponding minimal top-level `Makefile.am`.

Answer (score 0):

Gnulib assumes that your `configure.ac` file contains

```
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
```

Without it, every compiler command invocation is more than 1000 characters long, due to the many -D options; this is not practical for development.

Comment: After this string added I get errors in `autoreconf`:
`autoheader: warning: missing template: ICONV_CONST`
`autoheader: Use AC_DEFINE([ICONV_CONST], [], [Description])`
`autoheader: warning: missing template: LIBISOFS_VERBOSE_DEBUG`
`autoheader: warning: missing template: _GNU_SOURCE`
`autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoheader failed with exit status: 1`

Comment: Yes, `AC_DEFINE` wants a third argument nowadays. Fix the AC_DEFINE invocations in your code.

Comment: You don't need to define `_GNU_SOURCE` yourself when you use gnulib. The gnulib module `extensions` does it (and it does the equivalent thing for the other platforms as well).